# cron url setup on Ms azure

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, azure-web-app-service

I am using microsoft azure as a hosting.It is using Microsoft-IIS/8.0 server for running my Codeigniter website.

How can I setup my website few url's as a cron?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. `wget` will download the target page on you system. Are you trying to monitor your site's health ?

Comment: I want to setup my website url's as a cron in my azure portal

Comment: That's what you question says, but what do you mean by "setup" ? How can a wget can setup anything ?

Comment: Alexandre.if you know how can I pass the url's as a cron then let me know and why you give my question down vote

Comment: Because it is still very unclear of what you need. I'll remove it when it's clearer. Passing the url as a cron has no meaning by itself. What is it you're trying to achieve here ? Try to describe it with other words

Comment: I just want to know the place in azure portal their I can setup my url's as a cron. Makes sense to you ?

Comment: Hi @PankajSharma, any update?

Comment: Hello Gary. Thanks for asking. I created cron setup from this website "https://manage.windowsazure.com" and now it is working fine.

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE hi, I have changed the text of my question. Can you please remove downvote over it ? Or let me know that what valid text will be for it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding, you want to leverage an Azure Service or feature to make your several Url endpoints as schedule jobs.

You can leverage Azure Scheduler to achieve your requirement. For step by step guide, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal.

Additionally, if you want to make your internal PHP scripts as schedule jobs, you can leverage App Services' build-in feature, WebJobs. For more info, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-the-azure-scheduler.

Any further concern or if I have any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.